# How to change icons with the callback function?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, boto3, boto

My program allows me to drag an drop file into a box to be uploaded to a storage domain. Right now I have it so a progress bar appears and actually calculates when each file is completed with the callback function. However, the rest of my program says it is completed as soon as every file begins their upload, not finish.

My question is how can I change the icons of my images after each individual file is done uploading.

The storageDomain, awsID, and awsSecret are boto3 variables

```
import sys, os, threading, logging, math, time, re
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class ListBoxWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.resize(600, 600)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            icon = QIcon('loaded.png')
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                if url.isLocalFile():
                    rootPath = url.toString()[8:]
                    if os.path.isfile(rootPath):
                        address = rootPath
                        self.addItem(QListWidgetItem(icon, address))
                    else:
                        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
                            for file in files:
                                address = str(url.toLocalFile())
                                path = path.replace("\\", "/")
                                directory_name = path.replace(rootPath, "")
                                displayName = directory_name + '/' + file
                                address += displayName
                                self.addItem(QListWidgetItem(icon, address))

        else:
            event.ignore()


class AppDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1200, 600)

        self.listbox_view = ListBoxWidget(self)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Get Value', self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(850, 400, 200, 50)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.startUpload)

        self.qs3 = S3Worker(self.storageDomain, self.awsID, self.awsSecret)

        self.percentageBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.percentageBar.setGeometry(500, 300, 400, 30)
        self.qs3.started.connect(lambda: self.uploadBtn.setEnabled(False))
        self.qs3.finished.connect(lambda: self.uploadBtn.setEnabled(True))
        self.qs3.percentageChanged.connect(self.percentageBar.setValue)

    def startUpload(self):
        firstFile = QListWidgetItem(self.listbox_view.item(0).text())
        firstLen = len(firstFile.text().split("/"))
        for i in range(self.count):
            path = QListWidgetItem(self.listbox_view.item(i).text())
            splitName = path.text().split("/")
            if len(splitName) > firstLen:
                displayName = ""
                difference = len(splitName) - firstLen
                if os.path.exists(path.text()):
                    displayName += self.user + "/" + self.toolID
                    for dif in range(difference + 1, 0, -1):
                        displayName += "/" + self.timeStamp + "/" + splitName[len(splitName) - dif]
                    self.qs3.upload(path.text(), self.bucketName, displayName)
                    self.listbox_view.item(i).setIcon(QIcon("uploaded.png"))
            else:
                if os.path.exists(path.text()):
                    displayName = self.user + "/" + self.toolID + "/" + self.timeStamp + "/" + splitName[
                        len(splitName) - 1]
                    self.qs3.upload(path.text(), self.bucketName, displayName)
                    self.listbox_view.item(i).setIcon(QIcon("uploaded.png"))

        else:
            print("No File inputted")

class S3Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    percentageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, domain, awsID, awsSecret, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.domain = domain
        self.awsID = awsID
        self.awsSecret = awsSecret
        self._s3 = boto3.client("s3", endpoint_url=self.domain,
                                aws_access_key_id=self.awsID,
                                aws_secret_access_key=self.awsSecret)

    @property
    def s3(self):
        return self._s3

    def upload(self, filename, bucketname, objectname):
        self._size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
        self._seen_so_far = 0
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute, args=(filename, bucketname, objectname), daemon=True
        ).start()

    def _execute(self, fileName, bucketName, objectName):
        self.started.emit()
        self.s3.upload_file(fileName, bucketName, objectName, Callback=self._callback)
        self.finished.emit()

    def _callback(self, bytes_amount):
        self._seen_so_far += bytes_amount
        percentage = (self._seen_so_far / self._size) * 100
        if percentage > 100:
            self.percentageChanged.emit(100)
        else:
            self.percentageChanged.emit(math.floor(percentage))

        #I fell like I need to change the icons in here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = AppDemo()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

You say that your code works but I see many inconsistencies (apart from what variables are not created) so my solution will modify various aspects:

- If you are going to upload n files then you must have n QProgressBar.
- I did not understand the logic of your filtering in drag-and-drop, so simply, in this the complete path is stored and the name of the file is established through a delegate.
- Same for displayName.

Also the trick is to establish an identifier so that at the end of the load the icon is established.

```
from functools import partial
import math
import os
import sys
import threading
import uuid

import boto3

from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    Qt,
    QUrl,
    QObject,
    pyqtSignal,
    QFileInfo,
    QDirIterator,
    QDir,
    pyqtSlot,
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QListWidget,
    QPushButton,
    QProgressBar,
    QListWidgetItem,
    QStyledItemDelegate,
)

PathRole = Qt.UserRole + 1000
IdentifierRole = Qt.UserRole + 1001


class NameDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.text = QFileInfo(index.data(PathRole)).fileName()


class ListBoxWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.resize(600, 600)

        delegate = NameDelegate(self)
        self.setItemDelegate(delegate)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            event.accept()
            icon = QIcon("loaded.png")
            for url in event.mimeData().urls():
                if url.isLocalFile():
                    fi = QFileInfo(url.toLocalFile())
                    if fi.isDir():
                        it = QDirIterator(
                            fi.fileName(), QDir.Files, QDirIterator.Subdirectories,
                        )
                        while it.hasNext():
                            item = QListWidgetItem()
                            item.setData(PathRole, it.next())
                            self.addItem(item)
                    elif fi.isFile():
                        item = QListWidgetItem()
                        item.setData(PathRole, url.toLocalFile())
                        self.addItem(item)

        else:
            event.ignore()


class AppDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1200, 600)

        self.listbox_view = ListBoxWidget(self)

        self.btn = QPushButton("Get Value", self)
        self.btn.setGeometry(850, 400, 200, 50)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.startUpload)

        self.qs3 = S3Worker("storageDomain", "awsID", "awsSecret")

        self.qs3.started.connect(self.handle_started)
        self.qs3.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)
        self.qs3.percentageChanged.connect(self.handle_percentageChanged)

        self.percentageBar_container = dict()

    def startUpload(self):
        for i in range(self.listbox_view.count()):
            item = self.listbox_view.item(i)
            filename = item.data(PathRole)
            identifier = uuid.uuid4()
            item.setData(IdentifierRole, identifier)

            # this code is for test
            displayname = str(identifier)
            bucketName = "bucketName"

            self.qs3.upload(filename, bucketName, displayname, identifier)

        if self.listbox_view.count() == 0:
            print("No File inputted")

    @pyqtSlot(uuid.UUID)
    def handle_started(self, identifier):
        if not self.percentageBar_container:
            self.btn.setEnabled(False)
        percentageBar = QProgressBar()
        percentageBar.setGeometry(500, 300, 400, 30)
        percentageBar.show()
        self.percentageBar_container[identifier] = percentageBar

    @pyqtSlot(uuid.UUID)
    def handle_finished(self, identifier):
        if self.percentageBar_container.get(identifier):
            del self.percentageBar_container[identifier]
            model = self.listbox_view.model()
            indexes = model.match(
                model.index(0, 0), IdentifierRole, identifier, -1, Qt.MatchExactly
            )
            for index in indexes:
                item = self.listbox_view.itemFromIndex(index)
                item.setIcon(QIcon("uploaded.png"))
        if not self.percentageBar_container:
            self.btn.setEnabled(True)

    @pyqtSlot(uuid.UUID, int)
    def handle_percentageChanged(self, identifier, percentage):
        percentageBar = self.percentageBar_container.get(identifier)
        if percentageBar is not None:
            percentageBar.setValue(percentage)


class S3Worker(QObject):
    started = pyqtSignal(uuid.UUID)
    finished = pyqtSignal(uuid.UUID)
    percentageChanged = pyqtSignal(uuid.UUID, int)

    def __init__(self, domain, awsID, awsSecret, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.domain = domain
        self.awsID = awsID
        self.awsSecret = awsSecret
        self._s3 = boto3.client(
            "s3",
            endpoint_url=self.domain,
            aws_access_key_id=self.awsID,
            aws_secret_access_key=self.awsSecret,
        )
        self._seen_so_far = dict()

    @property
    def s3(self):
        return self._s3

    def upload(self, filename, bucketname, objectname, identifier):
        self._size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
        self._seen_so_far[identifier] = 0
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute,
            args=(filename, bucketname, objectname, identifier),
            daemon=True,
        ).start()

    def _execute(self, fileName, bucketName, objectName, identifier):
        self.started.emit(identifier)
        self.s3.upload_file(
            fileName,
            bucketName,
            objectName,
            Callback=partial(self._callback, identifier),
        )
        self.finished.emit(identifier)

    def _callback(self, identifier, bytes_amount):
        self._seen_so_far[identifier] += bytes_amount
        percentage = (self._seen_so_far / self._size) * 100
        if percentage > 100:
            self.percentageChanged.emit(identifier, 100)
        else:
            self.percentageChanged.emit(identifier, math.floor(percentage))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = AppDemo()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `def _execute(self, fileName, bucketName, objectName, identifier):
 self._seen_so_far[identifier] = 0` On this line I am getting `TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @Owen try again

Comment: Do you know any resources to learn about the identifier? My files are uploading but none of the handles are getting called.

Comment: @Owen I do not understand you

Comment: I have been unable to fully get your code to work, for me it never reaches the for loop where you start changing the icons. `for index in indexes` and it also looks like all the `handle_starts` preform and then all the `handle_finished`. Which seems like all the icons will change at the same time not when one file is completed its upload.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only execute the process once, you can call the upload function with a further `row` argument, then emit the `finished` signal with that row:

```
class AppDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.qs3.finished.connect(self.uploadFinished)

    # ...
    def startUpload(self):
        # ...
        self.qs3.upload(path.text(), self.bucketName, displayName, i)

    def uploadFinished(self, row):
        self.listbox_view.item(row).setIcon(QIcon("finished.png"))
        # ...


class S3Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    percentageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def upload(self, filename, bucketname, objectname, row):
        self._size = float(os.path.getsize(filename))
        self._seen_so_far = 0
        threading.Thread(
            target=self._execute, args=(filename, bucketname, objectname, row), daemon=True
        ).start()

    def _execute(self, fileName, bucketName, objectName, row):
        self.started.emit()
        self.s3.upload_file(fileName, bucketName, objectName, Callback=self._callback)
        self.finished.emit(row)
```

In case you are going to develop a more complex structure, you could create an uuid (using python's standard uuid module) use `setData()` with a custom role >= QtCore.Qt.UserRole on the new list widget item, and then use [`self.listbox_view.model().match()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) to look for that unique id with the given custom role.

Comment: Your code does change my icons however it changes them all at once, not really when the file has completed its upload. Which I think you warned me about, "execute the process once". Can you explain more on the custom role?

Comment: @Owen I'd suggest you to follow the answer given by eyllanesc, which does exactly what I suggested.